# Suggestions to upload image using jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, file-upload, upload

I have a form that has 3 inputs:

[1] text input field for a status update

[2] file upload (for a picture)

[3] text input field for attaching a link

The user toggles between each one depending on what they want to do. For example when choosing [2], inputs [1] and [3] are hidden.

All of these inputs are contained within a single form with id `posts_form`. Options [1] and [3] post via Ajax to different controllers.

My problem now is with option [2] because it is not possible to upload images using jQuery ajax.

Some solutions I've seen involve using the jQuery Form plugin, but I wonder if it would be possible to do image uploading without the use of a plugin.

For example this would be the code base for uploading which of course doesn't work.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'chat/upload/' + <?php echo $page_id; ?>,
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#posts_form').serialize(),
        dataType: 'html',
        beforeSend: function(){
              $('#loading').show();
            },          
        success: function(html) {
            $('#attach').replaceWith(html);
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#posts_form input').val('');
            $('.posts_link').val('');
            $('#chat_input').hide();
            }
        });
```

Any suggestions on what could be added / changed to permit image upload using jQuery only, without plugins?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best choice is this plugin.  You're wasting your time trying to do it without this.

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Answer (score 3):

There is no straightforward way to upload a file via AJAX. That is a limitation in HTML4. Workarounds are using an iframe or Flash.

In HTML5, a File API is introduced to solve that problem. Here's a demo of leveraging that API (using a Firefox 3.6+), which allows you to drag and drop an image and load it without sending it back to the server: http://html5demos.com/file-api. It also supports multiple files: http://demos.hacks.mozilla.org/openweb/DnD/.

You can read about [that specification on W3.org](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/), if you are keen.

If you cannot depend on clients to have browsers supporting HTML5's File API, you may either roll you own or choose to use a library that implements the iframe workaround:

- http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/
- http://jquery.malsup.com/form/
- http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/
- http://aspzone.com/tech/jquery-file-upload-in-asp-net-mvc-without-using-flash/

Comment: thx @william - i am trying jQuery Form but am running into problems in triggering the submit since my button is not rendered by using `input type=submit` -- [see here for the new question I posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462730/how-to-trigger-submit-using-jquery-form-when-button-is-not-rendered-using-type-su) -- I will also check your other solutions