# Form enctype="multipart/form-data" NOT WORKING

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have done testing for uploading a photo to MVC (the photo is sent as a parameter to an AJAX CALL) controller using a form, and now need to do the same but modified:

Original Source that works is:

```
<form action="/Home/Upload"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<label for="photo">Photo:</label>
<input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" />

<input id="uploadbtn" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

and Action code from the Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase photo)
    {
        // Verify that the user selected a file
        if (photo != null && photo.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            // extract only the fielname
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(photo.FileName);
            // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/C:/poze"), fileName);
            photo.SaveAs(path);

        }
        return Json(new { Success = true });
    }
```

This works, but in this case doesn't work:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="photo">Photo:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" />
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

and Action code is:

```
public ActionResult EditModule(INT ID, string Description, HttpPostedFileBase photo)
{
    if (photo != null && photo.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        // extract only the fielname
        var fileName = Name + ".png";
        // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Module Previews"), fileName);
        photo.SaveAs(path);
    }

    else
    {
        Status += "Error image";
        Success = false;
    }
}
```

When I debug EditModule, the value for the photo is NULL. 
I'm sure there is no problem with the javascript and ajax call.

Comment: What `javascript and ajax call`?

Answer (score 7):

You have set your controller and action name to null so the form doesn't know where to post to. Change the first 2 parameters to be the action name and controller name:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, 
                                   new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Comment: Works for me (but I am not trying to do ajax.)

Answer (score 2):

> When I debug EditModule, the value for the photo is NULL. I'm sure there is no problem with the javascript and ajax call

You can not upload binaries with ajax.  You either have to use a `<IFRAME>` or a Flash plugin.

See this answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6462673/70386

Answer (score 0):

When you put null in action and controller, MVC uses current action and controller.